# Android tabview - onpageselected?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, switch-statement, case

My overall goal is to show and hide layout based on page selected.

My problem:

*Only `case 1` works*
This is the only case that shows and hides the layout. Case 0, case 2 and case 3 will not show/hide a layout, however they both will `log.d("PageSelected", String.valueof(position))` correctly.

What am I doing wrong here?

I created layouts in my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 <FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:id="@+id/HomeFrag"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Home"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/SearchFrag"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Search"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/SettingFrag"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Setting"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I added a switch case to my on page:

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        switch (position){

                case 0: {
                    Log.d("PageSelected:", String.valueOf(position));

                    findViewById(R.id.HomeFrag).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.SearchFrag).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.SettingFrag).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    break;
                }

                case 1: {

                    Log.d("PageSelected:", String.valueOf(position));

                    findViewById(R.id.HomeFrag).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.SearchFrag).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.SettingFrag).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    Log.d("PageSelected:", String.valueOf(position));

                    findViewById(R.id.HomeFrag).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



                    findViewById(R.id.SearchFrag).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    findViewById(R.id.SettingFrag).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




                    break;

                }

                case 3: {

                    Log.d("PageSelected:", String.valueOf(position));




                }
        }



    }
});
```

Comment: Did you use a `FrameLayout` to contain your 3 layouts in the xml file?

Comment: No, I just added the layouts under the root relative layout. I'll try the FrameLayout and report my result

Comment: @headuck It didn't make a difference.  Only case 1 works for changing the layout.

Comment: Can you post the full xml? Also do you mean that there is no change in the screen for cases 0, 2 and 3, and only see SearchFrag layout for case 1?

Comment: @headuck I updated the post with the whole XML. If I swipe to the third tab(case 2), nothing changes. If I go to the second tab(case 1) -> third tab(case 2 ) -> second tab(case1), then the second tab layout changes. If I go back to the third tab the original layout from the app launching is still shown.